# How to implement realtime graph for sensor data?

Tags: javascript, sensors, temperature, canvasjs

I have connected temperature sensor to BeagleBone Black [BBB] board, after interval of 1 sec it sense the temperature and pass to BBB and beaglebone dumps it into mysql database on another computer. I want to show temperature data in graphical format. Graph should be updated after each second.

I tried various libraries like c3, canvasJS but i was unable to implement with realtime updates.
Sample Temperature Data:

1 : 32

2 : 33

.

.
.
.
so on..

Following is the canvasJS code which I tried

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var dps = []; // dataPoints

  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title: {
      text: "Tempreture Input From XBee"
    },
    data: [{
      type: "line",
      dataPoints: dps
    }]
  });
  var xVal = 0;
  var updateInterval = 1000;
  var dataLength = 10; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

  var updateChart = function(count) {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/smartfarm/admin/getGraphJson", function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(key, value) {
        dps.push({
          x: xVal,
          y: value
        });
        xVal++;
      });
    });
    dps.shift();
    chart.render();

  };

  // generates first set of dataPoints
  updateChart(dataLength);

  // update chart after specified time.
  setInterval(function() {
    updateChart()
  }, updateInterval);

}
```

```html
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width:100%;"></div>
```

Problem is that this code wont shift,It only adds new datapoints to graph because of this graph becomes too complicated to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i overcome the issue.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {

  var dps = [
    {x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},
    {x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},
    {x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},{x: 0, y: 0},
  ]; // dataPoints

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    title :{
    text: "Tempreture Input From XBee"
    },
    data: [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: dps
    }]
  });
var xVal = 0;
var updateInterval = 1000;
var dataLength = 10; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

var updateChart = function (count) {
  $.getJSON("<?=base_url("admin/getGraphJson");?>", function (result) {
    //alert(result);
    $.each(result,function(key,value) {
      dps.push({
        x: xVal,
        y: value
      });
      xVal++;
    });
  });
  dps.shift();
  chart.render();
  //dps.length=0;

  if (dps.length >  20 )
  {
    dps.shift();
  }
};

// generates first set of dataPoints
updateChart(dataLength);

// update chart after specified time.
setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);

}
</script>
```

I initialize dps[] datapoints array with some values. From server side after interval I retrieved only single value rather than tens of values. just added to datapoints and made following arrangement to shift the array.
ie. adding one datapoint and removing one datapoint.

```js
   if (dps.length >  70 )
   {
     dps.shift();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but it appears that you are only emptying your dps array when you first load the page:

```
var dps = [];
```

When you use the setInterval function, it seems that you are using a .push() on the dps array in a for loop and only using .shift() once.  I believe this is adding a set of ten to your array every time you call your updateChart but only removing one item from the array each time. Is this correct?

If so, putting that dps.shift() line in your for each jquery loop should solve the issue...

```
$.each(result,function(key,value) {
    dps.push({
        x: xVal,
        y: value
    });
    xVal++;
    dps.shift();
});
```

Comment: You are right @branden-keck I changed as you mentioned but now graph wont render. Graph is not showing any datapoints. Empty graph!

Comment: @VaibhavrajS.Roham Did the rest of the webpage render properly?  And, the graph rendered but without data?

Comment: @VaibhavrajS.Roham On second thought, it might be better for you to just empty the array each time you call the updateChart function, since you're going to refill the array from scratch regardless.  Try putting dps = []; statement as the first line in the function and take out dps.shift(); altogether.  Additionally, it might be a good idea to take the updateChart function out of the onload function since you call it anyway... leaving it in the onload might be causing issues

Comment: you are right it works as you said to empty the dps[] at last and load new values but problem is that it removes all values but I need to remove single value.

Comment: I got my silly mistake! here i am posting what I did.